# Applying changes to a new git branch from another branch

Tags: git

In my git project I have two three branches:

- `develop`
- `feature/one` - cut from `develop` and has extensive changes to it; has not been merged back into `develop` yet
- `feature/two` - **must** be cut from `develop` as well, but **must** initially (when it gets cut) contain all the exact same changes to it as `feature/one` has (and additional changes will be added to this branch as well)

For reasons outside the scope/context of this question, it is not possible to cut `feature/two` from `feature/one`! Its not possible to do this and then rebase to `develop`!

I'm hoping git has a nifty command-line (or set of commands) that I can run that basically tell git to cut `feature/two` from `develop` **and** apply all the same changes to it that exist in `feature/one`.

Otherwise, I am going to be (*painstakingly*) copying and pasting changes out of `feature/one` and into `feature/two` manually, which will be extremely time-consuming, burdensome and error prone!

Any options here for me?! Looking for specific commands to run!

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout -b feature/two
??? now, how to make feature/two look like feature/one so I can keep adding to it?
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout feature/two
git merge feature/one
```

This should merge all code changes from feature/one into feature/two.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge).

Comment: Thanks @Jay (+1), wouldn't I want `git checkout -b feature/two`, or no? If not, why?! Thanks again!

Comment: You will have to checkout feature/two, so that you are in that branch. Then you will be merging the changes of feature/one into feature/two.

Comment: OK, but currently `feature/two` does not exist! So I'm assuming its OK to use `-b` to create it, right?

Comment: -b just creates the branch and then checks it out. So, it's Ok. But, otherwise, you can always create the branch first and then do git checkout too.